# Cordova In-app Browser Limitations

Tags: cordova-3, inappbrowser

We are looking at trying to reduce the development time of a new app and so would like to use the Cordova in-app browser to use our existing mobile site.

This has lead to us wondering what are the limitations of the in-app browser with respect to HTML5 and external sites.

Is there a list of these limitations somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things to consider here.

1) InAppBrowser is technically referring to the plugin which supports loading a 'second' browser from your app.  See my quick ref video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkUUgwAnlxI

2) There are limitations on what external content you are allowed to show based on white-listing within the application: 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

3) The version of WebKit you have available depends on your device (different in iOS and Android for example) and isn't necessarily the same as the default browser:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044650/webkit-version-is-different-in-phonegap-and-android-stock-browser

I think what you are asking about is the WebKit version portion so my hedged answer is to lookup the WebKit version for Cordova/PhoneGap on your target devices and check a site like: http://caniuse.com/ and/or test on actual devices.

Generally, in our experience, the feature support is pretty close to latest on iOS and a bit behind on Android.  The guys at Famo.us are currently working on an updated builder that ships with a much more up to date version.